# Maximal ideals of $\mathbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, extension-field, dedekind-domain

Consider $R=\mathbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$.

Q1: Are there any field extensions of $\mathbb Q$ besides degree 2 extensions by quotienting out maximal ideals? I could not find any polynomial generates degree 3 extension or higher. I considered $I=(xy-1)+(x^2+y^2+1)$, and it looks like I got a degree 4 extension from this as $R/I$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space. Correct me if I am wrong.

Q2: Is this a Dedekind ring?

Comment: Sure: just pick *any* algebraic numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbf C$ that satisfy $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + 1 = 0$. Then map $\mathbf Q[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbf C$ by evaluation at $(\alpha,\beta)$, i.e., $f(x,y) \mapsto f(\alpha,\beta)$ for all $f$ in $\mathbf Q[x,y]$. This is a surjective ring hom. onto the *field* $\mathbf Q[\alpha,\beta] = \mathbf Q(\alpha,\beta)$, so the kernel is a maximal ideal and the quotient by it is $\mathbf Q(\alpha,\beta)$. For example, let $\alpha$ be anything (like $\sqrt[3]{2}$) and let $\beta$ be a square root of $-1-\alpha^2$.

Comment: The answer to the second question is yes: that ring $R$ can be viewed as $\mathbf Q[x][\sqrt{-1-x^2}]$, so you're adjoining to the PID $\mathbf Q[x]$ a square root of $-1-x^2$, which is squarefree in $\mathbf Q[x]$. That makes this extension an integrally closed domain for the same reason $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is when $d$ is squarefree in $\mathbf Z$ with $d \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$. (There's no analogue of the mod $4$ condition for quadratic extensions of $\mathbf Q[x]$ because 4 is a *unit* in $\mathbf Q[x]$.)